# Bash - Output to file without break lines

Tags: bash, shell

I have a simple file that when executed, it would take the file name, run it through exiftool, and produce that output to a file.txt.

The only issue I have is that when I print the exiftool output, I get it in good format with each element on separate line. When I later pipe it to a file, it shows without new line so all text on one line.

How can this be fixed?

Here is the code:

```
read -p 'File name: ' fileName
result=$(exiftool ./Files/$fileName)
printf "File Meta-data: \n $result\n\n"
echo  $result >> ./report1.txt
```

The third line prints the following which is valid formatting for my purpose:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.10
File Name                       : names.txt
Directory                       : ./Files
File Size                       : 46 bytes
File Modification Date/Time     : 2018:03:01 19:45:32-08:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2018:03:01 19:47:42-08:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2018:03:01 19:45:32-08:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
Error                           : Unknown file type
```

But when I check the report1.txt, I see the following format:

```
ExifTool Version Number : 10.10 File Name : names.txt Directory : ./Files File Size : 46 bytes File Modification Date/Time : 2018:03:01 19:45:32-08:00 File Access Date/Time : 2018:03:01 19:47:42-08:00 File Inode Change Date/Time : 2018:03:01 19:45:32-08:00 File Permissions : rw-rw-r-- Error : Unknown file type
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo

Comment: excellent the solution is printf  "$result\n" >> report.txt

Comment: No, that's wrong. How did you come up with that?

Comment: from the page...it works though...what would be your recommendation?

Comment: No, the page says to use `printf "%s\n" "$foo"`.

Comment: Ok thanks for that....both options worked

Comment: One option works by chance, the other by design.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

The problem is the unquoted variable in `echo  $result >> ./report1.txt`.

When you have an unquoted variable, all whitespace (including newlines) will be consumed by bash itself before executing `echo`.

Assume you have the variable `var="My String"`. To effectively execute the command `echo "My String"` you have to write `echo "$var"`. When you call `echo $var` (without quotes), bash will execute `echo "My" "String"`.
In this example it makes no difference, because `echo` joins its arguments (`My` and `String`) with spaces. But if your variable contains tabs or newlines, they will be replaced with spaces.

#### Solution

```
read -p 'File name: ' fileName
result="$(exiftool "./Files/$fileName")"
printf 'File Meta-data:\n%s\n\n' "$result"
echo "$result" >> ./report1.txt
```

#### Alternative solution

With the help of `tee` you don't need the `$result` variable. `tee` redirects its stdin to a file and stdout at the same time. `tee -a` appends to the file instead of overwriting the file.

```
read -p 'File name: ' fileName
echo 'File Meta-data:'
exiftool "./Files/$fileName" | tee -a ./report1.txt
```